# Typescript gives different errors in vscode than through webpack

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code runs an instance of the typescript compiler internally to power the in-editor error feedback. You can choose which typescript to use with the `typescript.tsdk` setting.

I now have a situation where I get a red underlining telling me about an error that I don't get when building through webpack with `ts-loader`. I don't see a warning during webpack building either.

So apparently the build is different and I like to know how that can be the case.

The error I'm getting specifically is a typescript regression in newer version that I could google in several projects. The message is:

> Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)

This question isn't about that specific error though, but about how it can come that the in-editor typescript disagrees with the `ts-loader`-loaded one even though they are the same version.

Comment: You use font awesome?

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh No, but I saw a ticket about this at their project. For me it is my own code that triggers the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should check if you use the same TS version. Open command palette (ctrl+shift+p) type "Select Typescript version" and there you can verify if the bundled version matches your workspace version, you can also switch versions there.

Comment: I'm sure that vscode uses the one in `node_modules/typescript`. I'm not quite sure how to specify what `ts-loader` uses, I always assumed it uses that also when present.

Comment: I think ts-loader dumps it into the console somewhere below the bundle list (like "Version: typescript 3.5.1"). You can also check that you don't have a separate typescript install under ./ts-loader/node_modules/